# Azure Cosmos DB: How to create read replicas for a specific container

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

In `Azure Cosmos DB`, is it possible to create multiple read replicas at a database / container / partition key level to increase read throughput? I have several containers that will need more than 10K RU/s per logical partition key, and re-designing my partition key logic is not an option right now. Thus, I'm thinking of replicating data (eventual consistency is fine) several times.

I know Azure offers global distribution with `Cosmos DB`, but what I'm looking for is replication within the same region and ideally not a full database replication but a container replication. A container-level replication will be more cost effective since I don't need to replicate most containers and I need to replicate the others up to 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Few options available though:

Within same region no replication option but you could use the Change Feed to replicate to another DB with the re-design in mind just for the purpose of using with read queries. Though it might be a better idea to either use the serverless option which is in preview or use the auto scale option as well. But you can also look at provisioned throughput and reserve the provisioned RUs for 1 year or 3 year and pay monthly just as you would in PAYG model but with a huge discount. One option would also be to do a latency test from the VM in the region where your main DB and app is running and finding out the closest region w.r.t Latency (ms) and then if the latency is bearable then you can use global replication to that region and start using it. I use [this](https://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-azure) tool for latency tests but run it from the VM within the region where your app\DB is running.

Comment: If I use Change Feed to replicate to another DB, then I have to adjust my queries to read from it. I was hoping Cosmos DB would have a built-in feature for replication without me having to change my queries. Also, Serverless has worse RU/s per partition limit (5K) and it's not intended for mission-critical workloads.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your queries are all cross-partition and each query is consuming a ton of RU/s. Unfortunately there is no feature in Cosmos DB to help in the way you're asking.

Your options are to create more containers and use change feed to replicate data to them in-region and then add some sort of routing mechanism to route requests in your app. You will of course only get eventual consistency with this so if you have high concurrency needs this won't work. Your only real option then is to address the scalability issues with your design today.

There is something that can help is this [live data migrator](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-live-data-migrator). You can use this to keep a second container in sync with your original that will allow you to eventually migrate off your first design to another that scales better.